# Trying to install Java ME SDK

Tags: java, java-me

I want to create my own Java MIDlets, like games and other stuff, so i tried to install Java ME SDK to get started. But when i install it i get [this problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWUpY.png)

What in the world should i do!!

I tried extracting the bundle.jar of the installer and running it with java -jar, but that didnt help. I even tried installing older versions of the SDK, the 9.0.4 version to be exact, but it didnt help neither.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Java ME SDK are you installing? Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Oracle Java Micro Edition Software Development Kit at this time is 8.3 released in 2018. The [release notes](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.3/release-notes-sdk/toc.htm#MESDR104) mention that it requires JDK 8. However I'm not sure if there are current devices that still support Java ME.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote down how to setup Netbeans to develop J2ME apps for the old phones that supported those [here](https://microgram.app/blog/001-J2ME-development-in-2023.html).

You cannot use current Java ME versions for J2ME apps that run on old feature phones; ME targets very different devices nowadays.

Copied over from my post the essential steps (on Linux/Ubuntu, but should be pretty similar on Windows. I wouldn’t try Mac for this):

1. Download and install NetBeans 8.2 with JDK 8u111
2. Download and install the Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2. During installation, point it to JDK 1.7, 32bit.
3. Go to Tools -> Plugins -> Settings and add the plugin repository http://plugins.archive.librebeans.org/catalogue/8.2/catalog.xml
4. Install the Plugin Java ME Mobility
5. Install the Plugin ProGuard obfuscator
   Tools -> Java Platforms -> Add Platform -> Java ME CLDC Platform Emulator, select the Wireless Toolkit folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple problem.Go to google and search for "Java SE DOWNLOAD" and open java official link then download .exe file of java SE and install on your computer.
And then installing will begin without any error.

Where Do you get "Java ME JDK" ??? I try a lot more  method to download it from java's official website 'oracle' but it can't gave me download link.

Then I go to 'internet archived' and installed from it; software succefully installed but when I open It can't show any thing.  Just open and suddenly close without giving any notification.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).